# How do I download youtube videos with Youtube-dlg?

Tags: youtube

I was looking for a GUI for the famous youtube-dl utility to download videos. I came across youtube-dlg software.

While I could install youtube-dlg just fine, but I can't get it to download any videos. I am running Windows- 32-bit.

I thought may be I'd need to download and install Python 2.7 and wxPython too. However, even after installing Python 2.7.11 and wxPython3.0-win32-py27, I can't get youtube-dlg to download any video.

Anybody faced this issue?

Comment: Have you downloaded this tool from this place? https://github.com/MrS0m30n3/youtube-dl-gui/releases

Comment: @pratnala No. I downloaded it from https://mrs0m30n3.github.io/youtube-dl-gui/